# cannot access result set outside the function using mysql in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I cannot access the result set outside its scope.

```
function getAllProducts() {
   connection.connect((err) => {
      if (err) throw err
      connection.query(
         'SELECT * FROM `men`', (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err
            return result
            });
         })
   })
}
```

I have tried reassigning it to a previously created variable by adding this `let res = null`, replacing return statement with `res = result` and returning res at the end of the function and instead.

I have also tried reassigning it by iterating through it by creating an empty array called res and replacing return statement with this :

```
result.forEach(element => {
    res.push(element)
})
```

I can console log it by replacing return statement with `console.log(result)` and it would work normally and print the result set.

I'm starting to figure out that it has something to do with the last line executing before callback finishes executing so it returns nothing. any help is appreciated to guide me to right direction on figuring this out.

Comment: What framework are you using to connect the database ?

Comment: I'm using express with mysql driver

Comment: Try passing a callback  to the function, because node-mysql is async